# How to sum across entire DataFrame with mixed types?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a mix of ints and strings.

```
In [81]: df
Out[81]: 
   0   1
0  1  hi
1  3   4
```

What is the simplest way to get a sum of only numbers across the entire frame?  In the example above, I would expect a result of 8 (i.e., summing ignoring the 'hi').

If the dataframe had only numbers, it seems like I could do df.sum().sum() or df.as_matrix().sum().

However, since I have mixed types, sum() doesn't seem to do what I want:

```
In [82]: df.sum()
Out[82]: 
0    4
dtype: int64
```

Using the numeric_only flag doesn't seem to change anything.

I noticed that if I specify the axis, I can get to the right results.

```
In [96]: df.sum(axis=0).sum() + df.sum(axis=1).sum()
Out[96]: 8
```

But I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: btw looks like your method is incorrect, try to run it on `df = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,3], 1:['hi',5]})`

Comment: Hmm, you're right.  Thanks Roman.  It was kludgy anyway :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but keep in mind that dtypes are per-column. So keeping mixed data in the same column is a bit confusing.

```
In [10]: df = DataFrame([[1,'hi'],[3,4]])

In [11]: df.dtypes
Out[11]: 
0     int64
1    object
dtype: object

In [12]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[12]: 
   0   1
0  1 NaN
1  3   4

In [13]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).unstack().sum()
Out[13]: 8.0
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  Re mixed data types, unfortunately, I receive my data as a list of lists representation of a matrix of mixed types, and I need to keep all of it for possible later processing.  I might look at immediately creating a numeric version of it so convert_objects isn't called each time I need a numeric result.